# What are the rules for saving people on the merchant ship map in Flash Point: Fire Rescue?

Tags: flash-point

The Merchant Ship map of the Dangerous Waters expansion for Flash Point:  Fire Rescue has a rescue position in each of the four corners. All of them are confusing to me. The bottom two look like they take up two spaces each because there's no definitive line separating the areas into halves, but the symbol is only in the very corner. The top two look like they also take up two spaces in a similar manner that can only be accessed from the 2nd and 7th columns. The written rules are very vague. Do the stairs to the corners have a function, or are they just for asthetics? Do I have to carry a person up the stairs to the rescue symbol?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the stairs effectively split the top spaces into two - see the designer's comment at https://boardgamegeek.com/article/14049646#14049646 . On that basis I would regard the top spaces as accessible only via the stairs.

At the bottom I'd regard e.g. (6,0) as the rescue space and (5,0) as where you go on your way out of it. On the other hand explosions (or Chop actions) can connect the bottom spaces to the cabins (e.g. linking (6,0) to (6,1)).

Comment: I don't see in that link a real specification of whether the rescue areas are separated into two spaces or not, just that the stairs represent the direction to exit and enter. The confusion comes because the ambulance in the base game takes two spaces, as well as the hospital beds on the Submarine (other side of ship board).